# Sorting cyrillic words with accents

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, dictionary, diacritics

I experienced a problem with sorting array of strings written in the cyrilica (with accents). The following solution sorts the strings with and without diacritical marks separately at the beginning of the string.

```
function sorting(){
    let words = document.querySelectorAll(".dictionary");   
    let unsorted = [];
    let collator = new Intl.Collator('ru', {sensitivity: 'base'});
    words.forEach(s => {
        unsorted.push(s.textContent);
    });
    unsorted.sort(collator.compare);
    unsorted.forEach(s => {
        document.write("<p>" + s + "</p>");
    });
}
```

**EDIT**
This is array before sorting:
`[..., 'áвтор', ..., 'авиабилéт', ..., 'янтáрный', ..., 'Áвстрия', 'áвтор', 'автостóп'];`
this is after sorting:
`["авиабилéт", "автостóп", ..., "янтáрный", ..., "Áвстрия", "áвтор"]`
this is what I want to have
`['авиабилéт', 'Áвстрия', 'áвтор', 'автостóп', ..., 'янтáрный', ...];`

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example which would include the strings to sort? Also have you checked what `Intl.Collator.supportedLocalesOf('ru')` returns? What browser (and version) are you using?

Comment: Can you also share the value after sorting?

Comment: I have added a list of words that illustrate the problem well.  It seems that the problem concerns only words that start with a diacritical character.
And `Intl.Collator.supportedLocalesOf('ru')` returns `["ru"]`. I'm using Chrome 62.

Comment: @gurvinder372 This is a list of words after sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I believe it's a bug in scope either ICU project or CLDR library.

Since characters with accent are typically combined and kept as single character then cyrillic 'a' and latin 'a' with accent become the same character. It makes standard sorting fail.

As a workaround I propose

1. normalize case with `.toLowerCase()`
2. using `.normalize('NFD')` expand single character into series of 'base character + accent character'
3. remove any diacritic chatacters with `.replace()`
4. use standard `.sort()`

I believe it should work.

Answer (score 1):

you have not provided `sensitivity` in [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator). Probably default value is 'variant'(I've tried in Chrome's console) while you need 'base'

Comment: I added `{sensitivity: 'base'}` but result is still the same.

Comment: `var a = new Intl.Collator('ru', {sensitivity: 'base'}).compare;
['áвтор', 'авиабилéт', 'янтáрный', 'Áвстрия', 'áвтор', 'автостóп'].sort(a);
=> ["авиабилéт", "автостóп", "янтáрный", "Áвстрия", "áвтор", "áвтор"]`

Comment: But this is the wrong order :) `á`-words shouldn't be at the end.

Comment: I've been surprised but simple `.sort((x,y) => x.localeCompare(y))` works just fine while `Intl.Collator(...).compare` does not.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work properly with larger set of strings with cyrillic signs. In that case, a second parameter should be added like this `.sort((x,y) => x.localeCompare(y, 'ru'))` - to specify which alphabet we want to use. And it works the same as Intl.Collator object.

Comment: I'm almost sure it's a bug in engine. Since accent character comes after main one I believe "a" should go before "я" regardless locale used. This way even encoding-unsafe `.sort()` works better than locale-based comparators.

Comment: I;ve found similar bug [reported](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=669063&q=intl&sort=component&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) for Chromium in Danish.

Comment: Maybe so. I thought I might have mixed diacritical characters from another alphabet, but even if I had to find a way to standardize them.

Comment: Chromium refers to [ICU project](http://site.icu-project.org/bugs) and that is refer to [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/bug-reports) so it will be hard to find out who is recipient of bug report :)

Comment: I'm not sue that diacritical signs are bound to any alphabet at all. They all are related to [separated section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) in Unicode(except Й and Ё that is included into alphabet)

Comment: I've just realized that á is not "а" + modifier.
`'á'.length` returns 1; `'á'.charCodeAt(0)` returns 225; while `'а'.charCodeAt(0)` returns 1072.
So this way was even `.sort()` would fail if I put accent not to "а", but say to "о". I'm more confused than at the start :(

Comment: @enk1 to my previous comment: there is a method `.normalize()`. using `.normalize('NFD')` it's possible to get diacritical as separated characters. So far default `.sort()` at least will not mess with á to be outside of range of Cyrillic. I see next flow to work: `.nomalize('NFD')` -> `.toLowerCase()` -> `.replace(regexp_for_diacritical_characters, '')` -> `.sort()`

Comment: It works fine for me :) I had a mess with different characters with accents. Update your response and i will accept it.

Comment: @enk1 to keep everything I've found during investigation I'd like to keep this thread unchanged and put another answer with outcomes.